# CI Bonfie VS Fuel CMS or Alternative

Tags: php, codeigniter

Firstly I apologies if this is not the place for this but I have been doing research for the past few days and my head is spinning a bit.

I'm looking for a base in which I can develop onto to build multiple applications. I'm familiar with Codeigniter and therefore was looking for something built using Codeigniter.

I'm leaning towards Bonfire or Fuel CMS but was wondering if anyone has used any of these and what their thoughts are on the 2 and if there is anything else out there that you can suggest

Comment: Have you tried asking on codeigniter forum http://forum.codeigniter.com/

Comment: No, not sure why I didn't think about that.